# NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element uisng selenium web-driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here i am trying to click a button using css selector find method.But its unable to locate the element. So i tried giving the time also but still its unable to click the element

Code sample -->

```
WebDriverWait waitr = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = waitr.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#userTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.sorting_1 > div > a")));
element.click();
```

My HTML body Looks as follows

```html
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="mainAnchor" aria-expanded="false">CA05
<span class="caret" style="margin-left:5px;"><span> </span></span></a>
```

If i use Thread.sleep(1000); instead of wait it works fine but i don't want to use Thread.sleep.Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Please, remove the horizontal scrollbars. This would be improve the readablilty.

Comment: We can't know for sure that your hierarchy is correct. If I had to bet, I would check the argument of `By.cssSelector()`

Comment: Please paste the exception!

Comment: If you are getting any error , please add..

Comment: If you are waiting for an element to click on it, you should use `elementToBeClickable(By locator)` instead of checking for visibility. Your question is confusing. You state that you are unable to locate the element but you also state that if you add a sleep it works. It sounds like you are waiting on the wrong thing or you have omitted some important details in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as `CA05` you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.mainAnchor[data-toggle=dropdown]"))).click();
```

Comment: It's not working ..It waits for 10 sec and gives exception like -->

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .open > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Have you tried my Answer at all? I don't have the `css` as **`ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)`** in my Answer.

Comment: yes I tried that error is actually of next line of code .when i click this button it opens an drop down and there is a delete button and many things.But now coming to the drop down when i click an element from the table it should give drop down that is what i am not able to get .so the next line throws error

Comment: But its not yet working ..Still the same error.Its not clicking only .It works if i wait for 100 millisec using Thread.sleep(100);But i dont want to use that approach ..

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use a fluentwait like the following below.

```
    static Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(elementWaitTime, SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(2,SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


   WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
      public WebElement apply(WebDriver aDriver) {
        driver= aDriver;
        element.click();
        return aDriver.findElement(cssSelector("#userTab a.mainAnchor"));

    }
});
```

Comment: Hii It's not working .The element is vailable but still Its not clicking the element.If i give Thread.sleep(100); wait for 100 milli sec it works fine .
What could be the reason ? It looks strange behaviour .

Comment: How much wait and polling time are you using.
Can you debug ?

Comment: Waiting time is 10 sec and polling time is 2 sec

Comment: as long as you are not getting a NoSuchElementException you can use JavascriptExecutor to click the element.

 using ("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", buttonOrWebElement);